# Why use a rectangular contour to evaluate $\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{e^{-i\sigma x}}{e^{ax}+e^{-bx}}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to tackle the following integral:

$$\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{e^{-i\sigma x}}{e^{ax}+e^{-bx}}dx$$

I am told that I should use a complex **rectangular** contour to evaluate this integral however I am unsure on how to proceed.

Also I would like to know what characteristic of this integral hints on the type of contour that I must use and the type of complex integral I should consider.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: $a,b>0$ and $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: The integrand denominator can be rewritten as 'something' $\propto \cosh$ such that it has infinite poles along the 'imaginary axis'. By choosing a $\mathsf{rectangular\ contour}$ you'll 'enclose' just $\color{#f00}{one\ pole}$ which, indeed, is the 'cheap way' to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume $a,b>0$ and $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$.
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-i\sigma x}}{e^{ax}+e^{-bx}}\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{(b-i\sigma)x}}{e^{(a+b)x}+1}\,dx $$
and the last integrand function has simple poles at $x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi i}{a+b}$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. If we consider a rectangle countour $R(M)$ with vertices at $-M,M,M+\frac{2\pi i}{a+b},-M+\frac{2\pi i}{a+b}$ we have that

$$ \oint_{R(M)}\frac{e^{(b-i\sigma)x}}{e^{(a+b)x}+1}\,dx = 2\pi i\,\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{(b-i\sigma)x}}{e^{(a+b)x}+1},x=\frac{\pi i}{a+b}\right)$$
equals $-\frac{2\pi i}{a+b}\exp\left(\frac{\pi(\sigma+ib)}{a+b}\right).$ On the other hand the contribute given by the integral over the left and right sides of $R(M)$ is negligible for large values of $M$, and the integral over the upper side is just a multiple of the integral over the bottom side. It follows that:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-i\sigma x}}{e^{ax}+e^{-bx}}\,dx = -\frac{2\pi i}{a+b}\,\exp\left(\frac{\pi(\sigma+ib)}{a+b}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{1-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i(b-i\sigma)}{a+b}\right)}.$$
I leave to you to suitably simplify this expression and get:

$$\boxed{ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-i\sigma x}}{e^{ax}+e^{-bx}}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{(a+b) \sin\frac{\pi(b-i\sigma)}{a+b}}}}$$

Comment: OK. Why this particular choice of contour? What is its advantage? Also, as M increases doesn't the contour chosen cross more and more poles? Maybe I simply haven't understood the contour you chose. Could you clarify?

Comment: @johnmelon: the poles are on the imaginary axis only, hence for every $M\gg 0$ the chosen contour encloses a single pole and the related integral depends on a single residue. With the choice of a rectangle countour we get a nice relation between the integral on the bottom side and the integral on the upper side, so the computation of the real integral becomes straightforward.